# Passing data between WPF windows using events with custom delegate type

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm passing a text from sub window to main window using events and delegates but I'm getting following error:

> The type or namespace name 'TextUpdateEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Can anyone help me with this?

**Mainwindow.cs Code**

```
namespace passing_data_btw_events
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MenuItem_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Subwindow f = new Subwindow();
            f.TextUpdated += new Subwindow.TextUpdateHandler(TextForm_ButtonClicked);
            f.Show();
        }

        // handles the event from subwindow
        public void TextForm_ButtonClicked(object sender, TextUpdateEventArgs e)
        {

            // update the window values from the event args
            //txtName.Text = e.Name;
            TreeViewItem child = new TreeViewItem();
            child.Header = e.Name; 
            treeview2.Items.Add(child);
        }
    }
}
```

**Subwindow.cs code**

```
namespace passing_data_btw_events
{
    public partial class Subwindow : Window
    {
        //adding delegate
        public delegate void TextUpdateHandler(object sender, TextUpdateEventArgs e);

        // add an event of the delegate type
        public event TextUpdateHandler TextUpdated;

        public Subwindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Add_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // this button click event handler will raise the 
            // event which can then intercepted by any listeners

            // read the textboxes and set the member
            // variables
            string newtextbox = NameTextbox.Text;

            // instance the event args and pass it each value
            TextUpdateEventArgs args = new TextUpdateEventArgs(newtextbox);

            // raise the event with the updated arguments
            TextUpdated(this,args);

          //  this.Close();
        }

        public class TextUpdateEventArgs : System.EventArgs
        {
            public string mName;

            public TextUpdateEventArgs(string sName)
            {
                this.mName = sName;
            }

            public string Name
            {
                get
                {
                    return mName;
                }
           }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please look into improving the formatting of your input. There is no point in having countless empty lines ... and your comments aren't exactly helpful either.

Comment: How can i add child node to the above Root node which is created?

Comment: And the child text is coming from other .cs file. should i use events and delegates again to get child node??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextUpdateHandler` and `TextUpdateEventArgs` are nested types because they are declared inside `Subwindow` class. You referred to a delegate correctly using `Subwindow.TextUpdateHandler`. Do the same for event type:

```
public void TextForm_ButtonClicked(object sender, Subwindow.TextUpdateEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: How can i add child node to the above Root node which is created?And the child text is coming from other .cs file. should i use events and delegates again to get child node??